# Language is not stored correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm doing an app that lets user to choose language and change it during runtime. I have an issue trying to store desired language. It runs correctly during the same execution the user changes language, but then in  next execution, it always gets spanish language (system language). Here is the code I use to store language:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (sender.tag==1){

        [defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ca",@"es", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    }else{

        [defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"es",@"ca", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }

    [defaults synchronize];
```

Many thanks

Comment: That looks like it should store the selection correctly. Can we see the code where you intend to load the language selection at launch?

Answer (score 0):

The system will override the value of AppleLanguages every time your app gets started.

A solution would be to store your desired languages in a separate NSUserDefaults entry and load them (write them into AppleLanguages) at every app startup.

Hope this helps